# How to decrypt a base64-encoded string in C

Tags: c, binary, jwt, base64

I've been bashing my head over this for a few days now, and i just can't figure this out.
I've got a string, it's a token i get in a JWT for auth, etc.

The token was created like so:

```
token = base64_urlsafe_encode(DATA)
DATA = IV + CIPHER_TAG + CIPHER_TEXT
IV = 16 bytes - initialization vector
CIPHER_TAG = 16 bytes - cipher tag
CIPHERTEXT = remaining bytes - encrypted(CREDENTIAL)
CREDENTIAL = <username>:<password>
```

Now, i can decode-base64 the incoming jwt, no problems. But my token comes up like this:
(changing some chars for security reasons, i only changed alphanumerics for 0s)

```
token" => "00_0000000000000000000000000000000000-00_000000000000000000000000_0000_00000000000000000000000_0000000000000000000000000000000==",
```

I can't decode64 to binary because it fails on the "_" chars and "-" and anything not base64.

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?
How can they say: `token = base64_urlsafe_encode(DATA)` if the token contains invalid (not base64) characters?

Comment: Base64 is an encoding, you don't "decrypt" Base64, you *decode* it.

Comment: @MarcoBonelli maybe i didn't complete the post. But after decoding the token, i need to break it according to the specification and DECRYPT using AES-GSM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JWT uses Base64url Encoding (which is a little different from the normal Base64). The differences are:

- Base64url replaces `+` by `-` (minus)
- Base64url replaces `/` by `_` (underline)
- Base64url does not require a padding character `=`